# Is password required for restricted database servers

Tags: linux, security, firewall, postgresql

I have a dedicated Database server which is have PostgreSQL 9.1.

This server has firewall. **Only** `10.0.0.3` is allowed to connect and access to this server via Firewall. All other requests from other ip's are rejected.

After allowing this IP, it goes to database server. In database server there is a user called `postgres`. This user `has` password. But, even with this, only `10.0.0.3` is allowed to connect to this database.

So basically, only `10.0.0.3` is allowed to connect and do stuff.

So, do i really need a password. Due to my custom script i want to remove password and connect directly without password. Should i do that?

At this point what is the benefits of making a password protected user for only 1 restricted IP. Should i continue to use it?

Or let me ask you with this way: If i remove password and set to "blank", what can happen -even if there is a ip restriction-?

Comment: Everyone can just assign a static IP to their system and *fake* their way into your system if you rely purely on IP-based restrictions.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Ouch. That's a problem. Actually i was thinking that right now if its possible or not. Password is necessary then. BTW, Besides password, how can i prevent them to do that?

Comment: Well, *everyone* is a bit of an overstatement. They'd still have to be in your subnet. But, either way. IP-based access restrictions are useful, but should not be the *only* way you're securing access. If you require a password **and** the correct IP, you already have 2 factors. The more factors you have in authentication, the harder it will be to gain access.

Comment: I see the point. I will look deeper into this. Thanks for the answer. If you could just add this as an answer (both replies) i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone on your local network could assign the given IP address to their system and, thus, gain access to your server.

IP-based access restrictions are useful though, when applied in addition to regular access restrictions, like requiring a password. The more factors you require for a successful login, the harder it will be for a potential attacker to fulfill all factors.